# Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000005

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I'm pretty new to embedded linux and I would really appreciate a bit of help. I'm trying to run a linux kernel on the [risc-v fpga](https://github.com/ultraembedded/riscv).
I built linux 5.0.0 with busybox initramfs and compiled with [this bootloader](https://github.com/ultraembedded/riscv-linux-boot), then I loaded the .elf file to the ram and got the following error

```
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Ignoring memory range 0x80000000 - 0x80400000
[    0.000000] No DTB passed to the kernel
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.0.0-dirty (lemoncake@lemoncake-950XDA) (gcc version 11.1.0 (g5964b5cd727)) #1 SMP Mon Feb 21 20:42:33 KST 2022
[    0.000000] initrd not found or empty - disabling initrd
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000080400000-0x0000000081ffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000080400000-0x0000000081ffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000080400000-0x0000000081ffffff]
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 7168
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 56 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 7168 pages, LIFO batch:0
[    0.000000] elf_hwcap is 0x1101
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 12 pages/cpu @(ptrval) s18508 r8192 d22452 u49152
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s18508 r8192 d22452 u49152 alloc=12*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 7112
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: selinux=0 root=/dev/ram rw console=hvc0,1000000 earlycon=sbi debug
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Sorting __ex_table...
[    0.000000] Memory: 20044K/28672K available (4619K kernel code, 162K rwdata, 808K rodata, 2502K init, 213K bss, 8628K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 0, nr_irqs: 0, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] clocksource: riscv_clocksource: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 38225208935 ns
[    0.000964] sched_clock: 32 bits at 50MHz, resolution 20ns, wraps every 42949672950ns
[    0.011671] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.144353] printk: console [hvc0] enabled
[    0.150619] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 100.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=200000)
[    0.158831] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.195096] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.201619] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.477065] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.578630] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.583664] smp: Brought up 1 node, 1 CPU
[    0.659321] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.799263] random: get_random_u32 called from bucket_table_alloc+0xa0/0x20c with crng_init=0
[    0.869138] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.877168] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.947256] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    2.517448] vgaarb: loaded
[    2.684003] clocksource: Switched to clocksource riscv_clocksource
[    4.701897] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    4.825810] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes)
[    4.839968] TCP established hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    4.850333] TCP bind hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    4.864189] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 1024 bind 1024)
[    4.881878] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    4.893763] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    4.933738] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    4.943948] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[   38.825356] workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=13 bucket_order=0
[   43.900897] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 254)
[   43.908191] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[   43.913134] io scheduler kyber registered
[   56.341540] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[   58.440165] loop: module loaded
[   58.840776] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[   59.071341] Segment Routing with IPv6
[   59.089525] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[   59.267534] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[   60.241092] Freeing unused kernel memory: 2500K
[   60.245932] This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
[   60.252956] Run /init as init process
FATAL: kernel too old
[   60.592541] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000005
[   60.597897] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 5.0.0-dirty #1
[   60.601681] Call Trace:
[   60.604578] [<c0274450>] walk_stackframe+0x0/0x108
[   60.608340] [<c0274690>] show_stack+0x3c/0x50
[   60.611969] [<c06d2cb4>] dump_stack+0x84/0xb0
[   60.615561] [<c027a060>] panic+0x11c/0x28c
[   60.619019] [<c027c8a4>] do_exit+0x874/0x8e4
[   60.622594] [<c027d554>] do_group_exit+0x40/0xac
[   60.626353] [<c0288454>] get_signal+0x110/0x650
[   60.630117] [<c0273b00>] do_notify_resume+0x94/0x384
[   60.634054] [<c0272dac>] ret_from_exception+0x0/0x10
[   60.638820] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000005 ]---
```

init:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
exec /bin/sh
```

[busybox config](https://pastebin.com/LqEwukT4)
[kernel config](https://pastebin.com/Hvb9BdSk)

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The error is right there though: “FATAL: kernel too old” Are you sure you built Busybox (and whatever else) against the correct kernel headers?

Comment: @DanielB Well, I didn't consider that. Are there any configuration options related to kernel headers in busybox menuconfig, or should I check kernel header of cross compiler?

Comment: Not sure there’s anything really to configure. Yes, you need the right kernel headers while (cross) compiling.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to build compiler with right kernel headers.